# Deserializing a SOAP response from a java web service in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I'm attempting to call a third party web service that was written in java from a component built with C# running the .net framework 4.0. The WSDL is located [here](https://reports.web.analytics.yahoo.com/api/IndexToolsApiV3.wsdl).

The issue I'm experiencing is that my C# proxy class will not de-serialize the response from the GetProjects method properly because it generates a class for Project but the response does not contain an element mapping to Project but rather an "item"  element with Project specified in an xsi:type attribute.

From my research of the issue, it appears that the de-serialization is failing because the Project node is coming back as `<item xsi:type="ns1:Project" xmlns="" xmlns:ns1="http://v3.soap.api.indextools.com">` but the proxy is expecting `<Project>`.

Because the proxy is generated automatically when adding the service reference and because I do not have the ability to change the web service, I'm curious about any work around for this issue to get my proxy class properly de-serializing the response.  This issue is not isolated solely to the GetProjects method.  I expect to have the same issues with other methods in the service so a way to solve this globally would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try changing the name that the Project is serialized into:

```
[DataContract(Name="item")]
public partial class Project { }
```

This should tell WCF to expect `<item>` rather than `<Project>`.

Because `Project` is a generated partial class you should put this into its own .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Project` extends `Item` it is common for Java SOAP APIs to return everything as the base type. Have you tried something like:

```
var item = proxy.GetProjects(...);
var project = item as Project;
```

Several of the Java-backed SOAP APIs I've worked with require this.

Comment: I believe he get's an error right when the proxy calls the method. Not when trying to parse the proxy results.